# New Server 2022 DNS server replicated from soon to be old DNS - clients have to use fqdn for one zone

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2022

I recently replaced the existing domain controllers with two new ones that also function as DNS servers. After testing that the replication was working, I renamed the new DNS IP with the old DNS IP, changing the primary and secondary DNS servers but keeping the same IP address.

My domain is xyz.org and the parent domain is xyz.com. On the old DNS servers, clients were able to access **name.xyz.com** without needing to type in the fully qualified domain name (FQDN). However, on the new DNS servers, the FQDN must be used. The two domains are not on the same network and there is no trust between them. Unfortunately, I don't know how the old servers were configured.

I have moved the FSMO roles, verified replication, and made sure the new servers have the same roles installed. I did not change any names and do not plan to. My internal DNS and everything else seems to be working fine. However, I would like to fix the issue of clients not being able to resolve hostnames of my parent without the FQDN. I can go to each machine and append DNS on their network controllers, but I'd rather fix it at the top.

What steps should I take to get my clients to resolve the parent domain hostnames without the need for the FQDN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read up on the GlobalNames zone. It enables defining any short name or single label name that you want. It's configured on each DNS server.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/dnsserver/set-dnsserverglobalnamezone

**Description**

The Set-DnsServerGlobalNameZone cmdlet enables or disables single-label Domain Name System (DNS) queries. It also changes configuration settings for a GlobalNames zone.

The GlobalNames zone supports short, easy-to-use names instead of fully qualified domain names (FQDNs) without using Windows Internet Name Service (WINS) technology. For instance, DNS can query SarahJonesDesktop instead of SarahJonesDesktop.contoso.com.

https://download.microsoft.com/download/e/2/0/e2090852-3b7f-40a3-9883-07a427af1560/dns-globalnames-zone-deployment.doc

Answer (score 0):

First of all, DNS is ALWAYS about FQDN. DNS cannot resolve short names. In practice you can resolve short names because client resolvers adds search suffixes according to your NIC setting or GPO setting (if in Windows AD environment).
If the xyz.com suffix is existing, then your old DNS has correct forwarding, but not so on your new DNS

Comment: DNS suffix search order could fix this, however it would not have changed due to the server replacement. Also, it would be unusual to have the search order include what they are calling the "parent domain" due to there isn't a trust. However, the GlobalNames zone could easily satisfy this for small numbers of static records. They stated that the original servers are "no longer available", probably a good idea to not turn those on and cause a massive outage.

Comment: @GregAskew. Not really.. Suffix is all about client side. When the query hits DNS server, the server then has to either resolve it locally, or forward it to other DNS servers that are responsible for that domain name.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replies. My issue was that we have a GPO appending the domain suffix search order.

Once I found that, I found that the permission granting users access no longer existed (showed as guid). Once I granted authenticated users permissions to the GPO, my users were updated and i'm back in business. Thanks for your replies.

Comment: remember to accept an answer, else we will be reminded until the end of the universe to solve this problem. thank ;)